# Count of numbers with exactly one digit $6$

Tags: combinatorics

How many integers from 1 to 100000 contain the digit 6 exactly once?

Something like $6 + 6*9 + 6*9*9 + 6*9*9*9 + ...$?

Comment: what do you think?

Comment: 6 + 6*9 + 6*9*9 + 6*9*9*9  something like this way

Answer (score 4):

1. Choose where to place your $6$ ($5$ options)
2. Assign other numbers to the other places ($9^4$ options)